# How to render svg file in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I want to upload a svg file and show preview in react, but I don't know how to convert a svg file into react component. I try to use `DOMParser` to parse svg-xml string to Dodument Object, but it is not working.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Upload, Button, Card } from 'antd';
import { UploadChangeParam } from 'antd/lib/upload/interface';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

function App() {
  const [svgs, setSvgs] = useState<Document[]>([]);

  const handleChange = async ({ file }: UploadChangeParam) => {
    console.log(file);
    let domparser = new DOMParser();
    const svg = (await file.originFileObj?.text()) ?? '';
    const ele = domparser.parseFromString(svg, 'image/svg+xml');
    setSvgs([...svgs, ele]);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ margin: 50 }}>
      <Upload name="file" showUploadList={false} onChange={handleChange}>
        <Button>Upload</Button>
      </Upload>
      {/* preview list */}
      <Card style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
        {svgs.map((SVGComponent) => {
          return <SVGComponent />;
        })}
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Instead of loading yet another library, do **not** convert it to a React Component. A native Web Component is shorter and faster: [<load-file> Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd)

Comment: thank you, that's a good suggestion, I've also got a way, maybe I can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` in react, it can also render svg string into document.

Comment: Just change a component's css background with the svg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following library to convert svg's. You can also add its cli commands to your package.json

https://react-svgr.com/playground/

Comment: thank you, I got a way to solve this problem, maybe I can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to render svg-xml string. such as `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: svgXml }}`
```

Comment: Not a good idea. you can also use img tag for this purpuse

Comment: yes, img can do this always, but it is not suitable for my business